# Apollo asyncData in Nuxt.js returns error

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, asyncdata

Nuxt.js full static (2.13) doesn't support apollo's smart queries, so I am going to use asyncData instead.

I have something like:

```
import homeQuery from '~/apollo/queries/home'

export default {
  asyncData(context) {
    let client = context.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
    client
      .query({
        query: homeQuery
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        return { data }
      })
  }
}
```

I expect to be able to use `{{ data }}` in my template. However, I get the following error:

> ERROR  [Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

made it work changing it as:

```
async asyncData({app}) {
  const homeresult = await app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
    query: homeQuery
  })
  return { home: homeresult.data.home }
},
data () {
  return {
    home: {}
  }
}
```

however this doesn't seem to work on the default.vue layout when testing the static site with `nuxt serve`, but only on pages. I found it working on layout with fetch():

```
async fetch() {
  const homeresult = await this.$apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
    query: homeQuery
  })
  this.home = homeresult.data.home
},
data () {
  return {
    home: {}
  }
}
```